# How can I parse Kusto timespan strings in C#?

Tags: c#, timespan, azure-data-explorer

I tried `TimeSpan.Parse("2d")`, for example, but that doesn't work.

The format of [Kusto timespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/timespan#examples) doesn't seem to be supported by any of the `TimeSpan.Parse()` flavors.

Comment: .Net's `Timespan` won't parse those formats.  You'll have to implement the parse yourself.  Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, though; can you share with us your attempt at parsing values like "2d" into a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Sorry about that. I figured there would be a Kusto [IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) or something like that. It certainly wasn't my intention to have someone write this for me :).

Comment: Neither a downvote or close as "too broad" are appropriate.  The question is very narrow and specific, and the asker has showed research by showing both a code attempt and a link to an authoritative source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kusto Data Client SDK for .NET (in the [Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data) nuget package) has a `CslTimeSpanLiteral` class that understands this format.  It contains several static methods for parsing strings to .NET's `TimeSpan` structure.

For example:

```
using Kusto.Data.Common;

...

TimeSpan? ts = CslTimeSpanLiteral.Parse("2d");
```

In addition to `Parse`, there is also `ParseNoNull`, `TryParse`, and `TryParseNoNull`.

Comment: The [client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data) documentation seems very poor. I also downloaded the package and I didn't find any documentation. Finally, I tried a quick Google search for `CslTimeSpanLiteral` but I am not getting any relevant results. Is there any source you'd recommend? If so please link to it in the answer, otherwise, it's still as good an answer as it can be, given the publicly available docs :).

Comment: I simply downloaded the client libraries and searched for an appropriate function.  I agree, the docs could be better in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeSpan.Parse` in c# does not recognize the Kusto timespan strings like 2d,2h etc.

We don't know your purpose on parsing it, but you can use some code like below:

```
        string mytime = "2d";

        if (mytime.EndsWith("d"))
        {
            mytime = mytime.Remove(mytime.IndexOf('d'));
            var dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(mytime));
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
        }
```